# Getting Attribute Error While Syncing Jupyter NB to Google Sheets

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to integrate my Jupyter Notebook with Google Sheets. I am trying to execute below code and it is giving me attribute error. Need your help to solve the same.

```
# Set the sheet name you want to upload data to and the start cell where the upload data begins 
wks_name = 'Sheet1'
cell_of_start_df = 'A2'
# upload the dataframe of the clients we want to delete
d2g.upload(rs,
           spreadsheet_key,
           wks_name,
           credentials=credentials,
           col_names=False,
           row_names=False,
           start_cell = cell_of_start_df,
           clean=False)
print ('The sheet is updated successfully')
```

I am getting below error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-6aac4a76409f> in <module>
     10            row_names=False,
     11            start_cell = cell_of_start_df,
---> 12            clean=False)
     13 print ('The sheet is updated successfully')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\df2gspread\df2gspread.py in upload(df, gfile, wks_name, col_names, row_names, clean, credentials, start_cell, df_size, new_sheet_dimensions)
     99     last_idx = num_rows + last_idx_adjust
    100 
--> 101     num_cols = len(df.columns) + 1 if row_names else len(df.columns)
    102     last_col_adjust = start_col_int - 1
    103     last_col_int = num_cols + last_col_adjust

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5268             or name in self._accessors
   5269         ):
-> 5270             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5271         else:
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

It will be of great help if it gets solved.

Additional Code:

```
cols = ['Cases']
mask = lk[cols].applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)))

lk[cols] = lk[cols].where(mask)
print (lk)

mn = lk.replace('NaN',0)
mn


rs=mn.groupby(['States and UTs','district','status'])[mn.columns[0]].sum()
rs
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to upload a Pandas series instead of Pandas dataframe (in your script it is called rs, and that is why it complains it has no attribute columns, because series don't have). Can you share some more information on how you define 'rs' variable?

Comment: @Albert Albesa Hi Albert ... True.... I have pasted additional code where rs is defined. Please let me know in case you need additional infor

Comment: Could you share how lk is defined or show an image of some rows? Otherwise it is complicated to reproduced, as rs is defined based on lk. Have you checked whether rs is at the moment of calling the function a series or a full Dataframe?